# Statements and Expressions in Java(The statement x = y = x = 0 is illegal??)

Tags: java, expression, statements

I am studying Java and am having a problem with the following question.

Which of these statements are true?

- a. Any expression can be used as a statement.
- b. The expression x++ can be used as a statement.
- c. The statement x = x + 5 is also an expression.
- d. The statement x = y = x = 0 is illegal.

The correct answers are b and c. However, I don't understand why those two are the answers. Can anybody explain it for me?

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: An explanation will only make sense if you know what's a "statement" and "expression". Otherwise, you need to look them up. When you do and it still doesn't make sense - come back with a specific problem.

Comment: thank you so much for your feedbacks! I rewrote my title! And looked up definitions of "statement" and "expression"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### a

Take the expression `a+1` for instance. This makes no sense as a statement as it does not change anything and is not possible.

### b

`x++` returns `x` and increments it afterwards.

As it changes the variable, it can be used as a statement.

### c

When you assign a value to something else, it returns the assigned value.

### d

This is possible because `x=0` sets `x` to `0` and returns `0`.

Then, it sets `y` to `x` (`0`) and returns this value (`0`).

Then, it sets `x` to `y` (0) (and returns this value (`0`)).

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about (D)? For me, most of the time, int x was defined like      int x = 1;     however, for (D), it seems like    int x    was assigned in a very weird format for me, and I might need some more explaination for that.

Comment: If you have the `int` variables `x` and `y`, you can assign `x` with `x=0`. As `x=0` is also an expression, it returns `0`. This means, `y=x=0` is the same as `x=0;y=x` and `x=y=x=0` is equivalent to `x=0;y=x;x=y`.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help!